# can I use event load offline with text file

Tags: jquery, load

I want to load a div which I have saved as plain text(file). I have this file in the same root as my HTML page. On my HTML page I'm trying to call this file with Jquery event load, like this:

```
$("#tab2").load("textfile");
```

It doesn't work. Is it necessary to do this online, on a server? I'm I doing something wrong saving it as a text file? Should I save as html, how would this look like in the code?

Comment: yes you have to save it as `.html`

Comment: Does this work offline? How would I put this in the code, like this:`$("#tab2").load("textfile.html");` This doen't work. Do I have to address the div in question?

Comment: in order to access it with textfile.html you would need to have that textfile located in the same directory as the file that uses the Jquery call.

Comment: I think I have to use the event ''get''....Im I right..?

Comment: @thepristinedesign Yes Im using them in the same directory, but Im doing this offline on my pc not from the server. Does this make a difference?

Comment: 3nigma's answer indicates taht you do need to use the server.  As far as I know you would be able to do other javascript commands without being on a server, but load apparently needs connection to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/load/

yes it has to be on the server