# jquery load() equivalent for offline use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for an equivalent to jquery's `load()` method that will work offline. I know from jquery's documentation that it only works on a server. I have some files from which I need to call the html found inside a particular `<div>` in those files. I simply want to take the entire site and put it on a computer without an internet connection, and have that portion of the site (the `load()` portion) function just as if it was connected to the internet. Thanks.

Edit: BTW, it doesn't have to be js; it can be any language that will work.

Edit2:
My sample code (just in case there are syntax errors I am missing; this is for the files in the same directory):

```
function clickMe() {
    var book = document.getElementById("book").value;
    var chapter = document.getElementById("chapter").value;
    var myFile = "'" + book + chapter + ".html'";
    $('#text').load(myFile + '#source')
}
```

Comment: If you put it on a local server, it will work without an internet connection.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not the case, both by experience and b/c of links like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100462/can-i-use-event-load-offline-with-text-file).

Comment: Edit: local SERVER, yes I think it will. Sorry. But I plan to distribute to people that don't have the knowledge to make a local server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve load() over the file protocol, no other ajax request is going to work for html files. I have tried even with the crossDomain and isLocale option on without anything success, even if precising the protocol.

The problem is that even if jQuery is trying the browser will stop the request for security issues (well most browsers as the snippet below works in FF) as it allows you to load locale file so you could get access to a lot of things.

The one thing you could load locally is javascript files, but that probably means changing a lot of the application/website architecture.

Only works in FF

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    isLocale: true,
    success: function(data) {
        document.body.innerHTML  = data;
    }
});
```

What FF does well is that it detect that the file requesting local files is on the file protocol too when other don't. I am not sure if it has restriction over the type of files you can request.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the JQuery load function in this context:

You would could add an OfflineContent div on your page:

```
<div id="OfflineContent">

</div>
```

And then click a button which calls:

```
$('#OfflineContent').load('OfflinePage.html #contentToLoad');
```

Button code:

```
$("#btnLoadContent").click(function() {
   $('#OfflineContent').load('OfflinePage.html #contentToLoad');
});
```

In the OfflinePage.html you could have to have another section called contentToLoad which would display on the initial page.

Comment: Does the target html page (OfflinePage.html) have to be in the same directory, or can it also be in a subdirectory? Right now it is in a subdirectory, and I don't think it works.

Comment: @preahkumpii - I tried with a subdirectory and it did not work.  Try adding it to the same directory as the initial page and I will get back to you if I find a work around for a subdirectory.

Comment: Remove the + and quotations from, so it reads $('#text').load(myFile #source)

Comment: and try doing alert(myFile) to ensure it is the correct directory